# Missing Value treatment for a character variable

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on this problem, where I'm having a hard time to impute or replace the missing value for a character variable.

Below is the code.

```
auto['No.of Doors'] = auto['No.of Doors'].fillna(auto.groupby('Aspiration')['No.of Doors'].transform('sum'))
```

Here, No. of Doors is a character variable with values 'two' and 'four' I'm trying to replace any NaN values in the variable 'No.of Doors' using groupby function based on Car Aspiration or Make with the Mode value.

Comment: Show sample input and desired output.

Comment: Also show the full error.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly your problem, you can fill `NaN` on the `No.of Doors` column with its mode value.

```
auto["No.of Doors"].fillna(auto["No.of Doors"].mode()[0], inplace=True)
```